# MongoDb - Export database to js script (similar to rockmongo export)

Tags: mongodb, codeception

Is there a way from the command line that I can dump a MongoDb database to a javascript file that can be interpreted by the mongo shell? I am looking for a way to do exactly what the RockMongo Export function does, but I need to be able to call it from a command line script. I've looked everywhere for something that does this but all I can seem to find is mongoexport and mongodump which don't seem to do what I want, as these just create JSON files.

The reason I need to do this is because codeception's MongoDb module requires a file in this format to restore the database after each test. I want to write a script to automate this process so that I don't have to constantly go through RockMongo and generate the dump.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no clue what the rock mongo export script does (you might want to give more details about that), but using [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) exports JSON and awk can wrap each line into an insert or sth.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else happens to find this, I finally found a solution that works for my scenario. I had to take Markus' suggestion and kind of roll my own solution, but I discovered a mongodb command called bsondump that made things much easier.

So in my script I first use mongodump to create a BSON file of my collection

```
mongodump --db mydb --collection mycollection --out - > mycollection.bson
```

I then use bsondump to convert that into JSON that can be used in [Shell Mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#input-in-mongo-shell-mode)

```
bsondump mycollection.bson > mycollection.json
```

Finally, I'm using PHP so in my PHP script I loop through that json file and wrap each line in an insert statement.

```
$lines = file('mycollection.json');
$inserts = [];

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $inserts[] = 'db.getCollection("mycollection").insert(' . trim($line) . ');' . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('output.js', $inserts);
```

I'm guessing there is probably a better way to do this, but so far this seems to be working nicely for me. Thanks for steering me in the right direction Markus!